# How to handle refreshed in a multi-user Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm building a simple Vue app in which an Account van have multiple reports. When I display the account, I have an infinite loader fetching the first 20 reports for the account. When thew user scrolls down, the next 20 will get loaded etc.

I set this up in a way that Vue calls the API with an offet. So basically `/reports/all?offset=0` will get the first 20, and `/reports/all?offset=20` will get the next set.

Now this works nice and efficient, the difficulties arise due to the fact that app is a multi-user app. So it can be the case that after fetching the first 20 records, another user created new report for the Account. Unfortunately these won't show, as the offset will make sure that any new record will get passed over.

Now I'm wondering what would be the best approach, out of the following two I already came up with (please note I'm also building the API):

- Instead of passing the offset, I pass an array of all IDs I currently already have for the account (so basically an array of 20, 40, etc. IDs of the ones I already fetched), This way new records will automatically be added as the first few of the new set of records I receive (sorted by last created)
- I get rid of the re-use of data, and reset all the reports for the account in the unmount callback, so that basically each time the user visits the component, all the data will be fetched again.

Really wondering what would be the best logic to implement in this case, or maybe an even better approach I didn't think about?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into cursor-based pagination. Basically, you use IDs instead of arbitrary offsets, so you instead fetch the next _n_ records in the sequence after the record with an ID of _x_.

Comment: But that would still give me the wrong offset wouldn't it? As the latest ID I have, could be an older one than another user created, or am I missing the point?

Comment: No, because whenever you request the previous/next _n_ records using a cursor, it will always fetch the previous/next _n_ records at that moment in time before/after the given ID. Unlike page-based pagination where—as you rightfully say—a number of records could have been inserted before moving from one page to the next.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approaches, but passing an array of all IDs might not be the best - this list will get longer and longer as more items are loaded.

The second idea is much better - load the data each time the page is loaded. If this view is the only one where the data is needed, then yes - trust client/server caching to handle the nominal case, and set the infinite scroll window to a smaller amount, especially if the reports are large. Do some testing to see how many seconds of perusing per article it will take to get to the bottom of the list, and use that as a metric to determine the "correct" window size. remember that there are slower connections, and use browser tools to throttle the connection when testing.

There are several other approaches to this I can think of off the top of my head.

- If the reports are displayed in temporal order, use a date offset. When the user scrolls down, get the previous 20 before the last date. You can actually use a temporal offset to scroll in both directions using this technique, so if they scroll up, you can load the more recent items.
- You can use any scrolling method and just display a toast/popup/indication when new data is created, with a link/button to refresh the content, scroll to the most recent, load the newest, etc.
- If you don't care too much about order, you can use the last id, along with the first id in the list (or date, etc.) and have the server return newly created items with it. You should probably let the user know visually that they are new items.